# Aligning contents of multiple instances of a flexbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a react component that displays a list of contacts. Each of these contacts is also inside a separate react component where they are generated. I would like to [align these contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J04Qm.png) uniformly but I can't seem to find a solution. Especially when one of the details become longer like the name, email, contact no., or the ID reaches multiple digits.

Here is the return of the contact item react component:

```
<li className={classes.item}>
  <div className={classes.content}>
    <h3>{props.id}</h3> /*ID of the contact*/
    <h3>{props.name}</h3>
    <h3>{props.email}</h3>
    <h3>{props.phone}</h3>
    </div>
  <div className={classes.actions}>
    <button onClick={deleteContactHandler}>Delete</button>
    <Link to={`/contacts/${props.id}`}>
      <button>Details</button>
    </Link>
  </div>
</li>
```

Here is the CSS that corresponds to the classes of the list and div containing the items:

```
.item {
  width: 1400px;
  margin: 1px;

  border: 1px solid #77002e;
  background-color: transparent;
  padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 4px;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.content {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;

  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

I'm still learning CSS and react so I apologize for the messy code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless to want to give each of the child elements specific widths, you may want to look at using a table instead.

Comment: Say I decide to put a specific width, do I apply that property on the h3 tag? or give a class for each h3 that prints out the specific detail then edit them there?

Comment: You could use `.content h3:nth-of-type(1) { width: 100px }` for example.

Comment: Add a max width and truncate larger text, or look into CSS grid instead of flex. You'll have to change the HTML structure in this case

Comment: Since this is clearly tabular data a `table` should be your first choice.. Second would CSS-Grid probably. Flexbox cannot align elements that do not share a parent.

Comment: Check `flex-basis` rule, which allows you to set a width for flex items.

Comment: Just an update, dantheman's solution worked. But will try your other methods. Thank you.

Comment: space-evenly + text-align:center are not compatible with what you want i believe, are you trying someting alike : https://jsfiddle.net/ky9ehm8j/ ?  (is width:1400px really your need or was it for testing)

Comment: Tried G-Cyrillus' solution and it was also successful and much less code. Thank you.